# Ajax post to Python server: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json

I am getting this error from the server:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

This is the ajax request from the client-side

```
function searchDB(profile_url) {
    console.log(profile_url);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/update_greenhouse',
        data: JSON.stringify(profile_url),
        contentType: "application/json"
    })
}
```

Server code:

```
@app.route('/update_greenhouse', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def update_gh():
  y = request.data
  print(y)
  json.loads(y)
```

I am setting the `contentType` to be JSON. Why is the server giving me that error?

Comment: use `request.get_json()`

Comment: Sending `profile_url` is that really a json object?... sounds like it's just a url... maybe you need to convert  it really to a json object `{profileUrl: profile_url}`?

Comment: added `JSON.stringify()` in the AJAX request same problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not sending proper JSON to the server. Just setting the contentType isn't enough. Your data (`profile_url`) needs to be encoded properly, as JSON object.

Try something like this in your request code:

```
data: JSON.stringify({'url': profile_url})
```

Your server will then get a basic dictionary back to use. If you really want to just pass a string, you can forgo the `json.loads()` on the server and operate direction from `request.data`, but for building anything more than a hello world app, I'd strongly suggest using a more structured format like JSON.

You also need to return a response (or error) for every Flask request. If you're building a JSON-based API, I'd suggest using Flask's `jsonify`. Something along the lines of

```
return flask.jsonify({'status': 'updated'})
```

on success, possibly with details about whatever the updated state is. If there are errors, you should return a response with the proper error code, like so:

```
return flask.make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Error details'}), 418)
```

Replacing `418` with whatever the appropriate [HTTP error code](https://httpstatuses.com) may be.

Comment: doesn't `JSON.stringify()` do that?

Comment: You need to pass an actual JSON object.

Comment: isn't a string a valid json object?

Comment: Nope. A valid JSON object needs to have a root object. See my edit.

Comment: @MorganAllen updated with a bit more info and a solution. If that's helpful, please upvote or mark as answered.

Comment: so for some reason, i don't know what I did, but I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but it was `"OPTIONS"` in the `methods=[]` caused the issue. Removed it and everything worked.